# Code Iris plugin on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to make code iris plugin work on Android studio.

I press right click -> Create Code Iris graph and then I get a notification that my graph is ready. But I do not know when this graph is stored, what is the name of the file created and how to open it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I just Stuck on the same issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Complete Guidance of CODE IRIS Graph Creation:-**

You have to generate Code Iris by just right clicking on project, and then select **"Create Code Iris Graph"**, (Check the snapshot below)

[image]

Now your graph will be created, you can get the graph on the **right side of Android studio** (Check the below snapshot)

[image]

Comment: how we can export to pdf or png?

Comment: @RajiAC I don't think so, I am also searching for such tool.

Comment: we used Visual Paradigm- stand alone app,not a plugin in android studio

Comment: Yes, Visual Paradigm is also a nice tool. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I'll create such as diagram and i'll take a **screenshot** and save into a `.jpeg` file not convert to **png or pdf :)**  @RajiAC

Answer (score 3):

You may access it via the vertical panel at the right of your screen in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a directory marked as "Sources", e.g. your src directory.

You can do this e.g. in the Project Files Tool Window:
There is a context menu "Mark Directory as ..." > "Sources Root" for the directories.