# Using Code Iris with Intellij to generate class diagram

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Using Code Iris with Intellij to generate class diagram. It says diagram generation on doing right click and generate diagram. But I am not able to locate where it is getting generated. Any clues ?

Comment: IntelliJ has a built in feature for generating UML diagrams. Why would you want to use something else?

Comment: It does not have that feature in community edition.

Comment: Related : [Code Iris plugin on Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758761/code-iris-plugin-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to restart IDEA even after the plugin-required restart was performed.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you are using community edition and have installed the Plugin Iris properly, what you could do is:

Right Click on the package and select Generate Graph

You should see similar output as below:

> 12:24 PM   Diagram created: Indexed diagram of 1 modules, 5 packages and 5 classes in 0 seconds

Click on View >> Tool Window >> Code Iris

You should see the diagrams now.

Comment: I have two modules 1, main_ewp 2, test_ewp. When I click on generate graph, a dialog box appears asking me to choose the module, I click main_ewp and I get 'Indexed diagram of 0 modules, 0 packages and 0 classes in 0 seconds'. Did anyone got this issue ?

Comment: is there any documentation on this plugin? apart from http://plugin.codeiris.com/what-is-it/ e.g. how do I filter test classes from the diagram.

Comment: @AnumSheraz, Yes, I've got the same issue. The solution is to mark that folder as "Sources". In my case I had org/mypackage/blabla directly under the project folder, so I first moved them under a folder called "src" and marked it as "Sources". Then the "Create Graph" operation will work.

Comment: @SorinPostelnicu - New to IntelliJ - I have the same issue  as AnumSheraz.  Where do I mark the folder as sources to enable me to generate the class diagrams?

Comment: @adbdkb: Click on "File -> Project structure", then on "Modules", then click on the name of your module inside the list, then click on the tab called "Sources", then inside the tree of folders select your folder (for example "src") and then click on the "Mark as: Sources", then OK. ;)

Comment: There is no tab "Sources" in Android Studio 2023.1.1 :-/

Comment: There is a context menu "Mark Directory as ..." > "Sources Root" for the directories in the Project Files Tool Window

Answer (score 13):

Detailed answer of using Code Iris with Intellij to generate UML diagram
————————————————————————————————

Firstly, right click on the project and select `Create Graph`.

[image]

Then, select the module from where you would like to create the UML graph. Afterward, hit `ENTER` and the graph is generated.

[image]

As the graph is created, go `View -> Tool Windows -> Code Iris`
[image]

You can see the graph and select the views (i.e. package view etc) for the virtualization if required.

[image]

You can save it from the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that marking the "src" folder as Sources Root is required for Code Iris to generate the graph.